# Paypal credit cart payment not working in javascript project

Tags: javascript, paypal

in paypal credit cart payment method in some cases i get this error **ppxo_inline_guest_unhandled_error** is imposible to catch them in events.
Also **https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/graphql?fetch_credit_form_submit** api call gives 500 server error.
In payment with account i don't get this error.
I'm using sandbox account, can this be the reason?

Comment: Will need steps to reproduce, or more specific error response details from the Network tab, including the full error text of the response

Comment: @PrestonPHX mostly I have errors like that `country: ""
handledErrors: Array(1)
 0:billingAddress:
    contentKey: "fieldErrors.postalCodeInvalid"
    field: "postalCode"
env: "sandbox"
host: "www.sandbox.paypal.com"
inline_guest_version: "2.12.7"
lang: "tr"
pageID: ""
path: "/smart/card-fields"
referer: "www.sandbox.paypal.com"
timestamp: 
uid: ""
unhandledErrors: []
ver: ""
windowID: ""`

Comment: @PrestonPHX I think form validation doesn't work

Comment: Maybe it is [this issue](https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout-components/issues/1550)

Answer (score 0):

I humbly propose to in javascript subclass `window.console` and catch the error
`ppxo_inline_guest_unhandled_error`
then append your custom error handling code.

Comment: You misunderstood the concepts of StackOverflow if you think that an answer gets judged to be a solution, especially by the author. Answers on StackOverflow only get rated by usefulness. Please take the [tour].

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).